# Intercept back button in page and ignore it from iFrame - VueJS

Tags: javascript, iframe, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

**Hello,**

with the architecture we have, I encountered a weird behavior:
A page made with `VueJS` and inside some pages we have an `iFrame` that shows an application using `VueJS`

**The problem!**

- When clicking on the navigator back button for the first/second time nothing happens but in the third time, history goes back (navigation works)
- First Assemption is that the iframe intercepts the back button event
  rather than the parent page, which is not what we want.
- The solution shouldn't mess with the app from the iframe.

In the parent I've got it like:

```
Vue.use(Router)

export default new Router({
  mode: 'history',
  routes: [...routes]
})
```

Anybody has some insight? 
Thank you